# React is not updating props of a component passed as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have a React DOM that looks like this:

[image: DOM structure]

In `MarketDepthWindow`'s state i have a `isBackgroundEnabled` which i want to pass as a props to the `AskOrdersTab`. But it passes only the initial props and not updating. It should update on `MarketDepthHeaderComponent`'s button click.

I assume that the problem is that i pass it as a prop to `TabsContainer`.

I tried changing `React.Component` to `React.PureComponent`, using `shouldComponentUpdate()`, adding `React.cloneElement` and passing props through the `TabsContainer` but nothing works for me.

Maybe I made some kind of architectural mistake? Maybe i should use refs in some way?

```
class AskOrdersTab extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>bids</div>
  }
}

class BidOrdersTab extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>asks</div>
  }
}

class MarketDepthHeaderComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <button class={this.props.isBackgroundEnabled ? 'active' : ''} onClick={this.props.handleBackgroundButtonClick}></button>
  }
}

class TabsContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      tabs: props.tabs.tabs || [],
      tabHeaderComponent: props.tabs.tabHeaderComponent || ''
    }
  }

  renderComponents() {
    let tabsComponents = [];
    for (let tab of this.state.tabs.length) {
      tabsComponents.push(
        <div>{tab.component}</div>
      )
    }
    return tabsComponents;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.tabHeaderComponent}
        {this.renderComponents()}
      </>
    );
  }
}

class MarketDepthWindow extends React.Component {

  handleBackgroundButtonClick = (event) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      isBackgroundEnabled: !prevState.isBackgroundEnabled
    }))
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isBackgroundEnabled: true,
      handleBackgroundButtonClick: this.handleBackgroundButtonClick
    }
  }

  render() {
    let tabsProps = {
      tabs: [
        { title: 'Bid', component: <BidOrdersTab {...this.state} /> },
        { title: 'Ask', component: <AskOrdersTab {...this.state} /> }
      ],
      tabHeaderComponent: <MarketDepthHeaderComponent {...this.state} />
    }
    return <TabsContainer tabs={tabsProps} isBackgroundEnabled={this.state.isBackgroundEnabled} />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MarketDepthWindow />,
  document.getElementById("market-depth-window")
);
```

Comment: do you mean it doesn't update state of a component passed as prop?

Comment: Sounds kind of silly, but don't you still have to call props as "this.props" not just props, even inside the constructor. Kind of weird now that I think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state within TabsContainer is redundant, you should avoid storing state in each component as it cuts the update chain, Try using props instead.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

class AskOrdersTab extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>bids</div>;
  }
}

class BidOrdersTab extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>asks</div>;
  }
}

class MarketDepthHeaderComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        {this.props.isBackgroundEnabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class TabsContainer extends React.Component {
  renderComponents() {
    let tabsComponents = [];
    for (let tab of this.props.tabs.tabs) {
      tabsComponents.push(<div key={tab.title}>{tab.component}</div>);
    }
    return tabsComponents;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.tabs.tabHeaderComponent}
        {this.renderComponents()}
      </>
    );
  }
}

class MarketDepthWindow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isBackgroundEnabled: true
    };
  }

  handleBackgroundButtonClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      isBackgroundEnabled: !this.state.isBackgroundEnabled
    });
  };

  render() {
    let tabsProps = {
      tabs: [
        { title: "Bid", component: <BidOrdersTab {...this.state} /> },
        { title: "Ask", component: <AskOrdersTab {...this.state} /> }
      ],
      tabHeaderComponent: (
        <MarketDepthHeaderComponent
          onClick={this.handleBackgroundButtonClick}
          isBackgroundEnabled={this.state.isBackgroundEnabled}
        />
      )
    };
    return (
      <TabsContainer
        tabs={tabsProps}
        isBackgroundEnabled={this.state.isBackgroundEnabled}
      />
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("market-depth-window");
ReactDOM.render(<MarketDepthWindow />, rootElement);
```

This is your demo, you can check the fix and make sure it works. Good Luck

Comment: Thanks a lot! In fact, the mistake was that I used state instead of props. I removed all excess states, and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is that your storing `AskOrdersTab` in the state of `TabsContainer`, and in your case you want to access it via props.

Explanation: What this has caused is whenever your component updates, which it is doing, `TabsContainer` will still render the original `AskOrdersTab` (this is due to the `AskOrdersTab` in state and the current version with updated props being the same object). There are ofcourse workarounds for this sort of behaviour using lifecycle hooks, namely getDerivedStateFromProps. But in this case I wouldn't advise that.

TL;DR replace your `TabsContainer` with this one and it should work.

```
class TabsContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tabHeaderComponent: props.tabs.tabHeaderComponent || '',
    };
  }

  renderComponents() {
    let tabsComponents = [];
    for (let tab of this.props.tabs.tabs) {
      tabsComponents.push(<div>{tab.component}</div>);
    }
    return tabsComponents;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.tabHeaderComponent}
        {this.renderComponents()}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Finally, I think you're storing too much in state. Try importing components, or take a look at two common react patterns:

- Higher Order Components
- Render Props

Comment: Thank you! I looked at these patterns. Now everything fell into place.